# Re-sizing an image to fill another shape in easel.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs

I am trying to figure out how to re-size an image to fill another shape. I can get the image from preload.js but none of the re-sizing function that I have tried seem to work. I do not want to scale it unless that is the only way to make the image fit. The other shape is a simple rectangle but other shapes will eventually be used. The code to fill the rectangle is the following which works but not the re-sizing of the image to the size of the rectangle:

`var image = this.queue.getResult("imagePath");`
`var g = this.shape.graphics;`
`g.beginBitmapFill(image, "no-repeat");`
`g.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 140);`

I'm basically trying to do: 
`context.drawImage(Object image,float dx, float dy, [Optional] float dw, float dh)`

but with beginBitmapFill in EaselJS or any other function recommended

Comment: Have you tried using the matrix2D parameter in the beginBitmapFill method ?

Comment: I have not, can you provide an example for me to follow?

Comment: Here is an [example](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/createjs/324-how-to-use-scaled-image-for-beginbitmapfill-on-shapes).